# Is it possible to decouple row size estimation from maximum column width?

Tags: sql-server, optimization

In other words, is it possible to declare a column `VARCHAR(n)` and have the estimated size be something other than `n/2`?

An example use-case might be storing URLs - you expect most to be relative and less than 20 characters or so (eg "About/AboutUs"), but want to support the occasional long URL with lots of query string parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

I don't believe this is possible.

In the case that the average length is **greater** than that calculated by the heuristic but still less than 4,000 bytes it is possible to massage this upwards with a `CAST` but even then you  might need some hacking about with the query syntax to encourage the `CAST` to happen before any memory consuming operator that depends on the estimated row size.

In the case that it is **less** the `CAST` to a shorter size obviously won't work without the possibility of truncating data.

The possible down side of a mis-estimate is that the memory grant may be calculated based on incorrect information.

I've wondered before why the statistics on string columns don't keep track of this. Maybe in the scale of things it simply isn't regarded as objectively that important.